# Is it possible to implement cross-browser username/password autocomplete in GXT?

Tags: gwt, autocomplete, cross-browser, gxt

Last night, I did a quick spike to try and implement username/password autocomplete in my GXT application. By "autocomplete", I don't mean Ajax-style autocomplete, but rather browser-based autocomplete. The best information I found on this via google is in the following post:

http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleWebToolkit/2009-04/msg01838.html

I didn't use this technique because I'm using GXT and didn't want to lose the look-and-feel of my login form.

I was successful in getting everything to work in Firefox (it populates both the username and password). In IE, it only populates the username, not the password. In Safari/Chrome, it doesn't work at all.

Here's how I did it:

- Created a hidden HTML form on my HTML page that embeds GWT.

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value=""/>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login"/>
</form>
```

- When a user clicks on the "Login" button in my GWT application, populate the fields in this hidden form and "click" on the Login button (which will do nothing since the action="javascript:void(0)".

```
// Set the hidden fields to trigger the browser to remember
DOM.getElementById("username").setAttribute("value", username.getValue());
DOM.getElementById("password").setAttribute("value", password.getValue());
clickFormLogin();

...

public static native void clickFormLogin() /*-{
$doc.getElementById("login").click();
}-*/;
```

This works in Firefox 3.5 and prompts me to save the user/pass at the top of the screen. I believe I know why this doesn't work in Safari/Chrome and that's because the form's action doesn't go anywhere and the form is not submitted. If I change the action to be an actual URL and show the form, clicking on the form's Login button will save it in those browsers.

After typing this up as a question here, I got to thinking this might make a good blog post. Therefore, I copied everything and added a bit to my blog:

http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/browser_based_username_password_autocomplete

**Summary and Question**
While I'm glad I got it working in Firefox, I'm disappointed with IE's lack of password autocompletion. More than anything, I can't help but think there's a way to make this work in WebKit-based browsers.

Anyone know how to implement cross-browser username/password autocomplete in GWT (specifically GXT)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use persistent Cookies instead.
2. IE do save passwords, if user chooses to, but it works different. You need to type at least the username so it will autocomplete the password.

Answer (score 0):

You need a plain vanilla html submit button.  I think that will fix it.

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/2b2ce0b6aaa82461